# How to change Xmx settings for sonar runner?

Tags: java, docker, sonarqube

I have a Sonarqube instance running as a docker container. Since I updated it to version 7.1 the analysis of my greatest project fails with `GC limit exceeded`. If I restart the server, it might succeed once. After a while of researching this issue, I am tempted to believe, I need to increase the `Xmx` value for the background task.

Where and how can I configure this parameter?

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker-postgres/etc:/etc/postgresql
      - /opt/docker-postgres/log:/var/log/postgresql
      - /opt/docker-postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: sonar
      POSTGRES_USER: <SONAR_USER>
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <SONAR_PASSWORD>

  sonar:
    image: sonarqube:alpine
    container_name: sonar
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME: <SONAR_USER>
      SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD: <SONAR_PASSWORD>
      SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/sonar
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker-sonar/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - /opt/docker-sonar/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - /opt/docker-sonar/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - /opt/docker-sonar/bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put a `sonar.properties` file under `/opt/docker-sonar/conf/`. This file will be available inside the container under `/opt/sonarqune/conf/`, because the folder gets mounted as volume.

A full example for a `sonar.properties` file can be found on [github](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-application/src/main/assembly/conf/sonar.properties). However all you need to enter is:

```
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx<XMX_VALUE -Xms<XMS_VALUE> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Comment: Which file do you suggest to change?

Comment: In sonar directory you need to add sonar.properties file which sonar config file and copy it Dockerfile using 'ADD' command of Dockerfile

Comment: Please provide a code example in your answer. I only understand vaguely what you are proposing.

Comment: [sonar.properties](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-application/src/main/assembly/conf/sonar.properties) using this link you get sonar.properties file content. You need to update Xmx value which you want and add it using docker file

Comment: you can use command like : `ADD sonar.properties /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties` to add conf file using Dockerfile